# Como verificar se a entidade já existe no banco

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Atualmente estou a trabalhar com models, migrations,seeds e fakers (factory) para testes na base de dados.

Até agora estou a mandar inserir 1 admin, cujo código passo a apresentar:

```
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'id'=>'1',

        'name' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('admin'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ]);

}}
```

O meu problema é que eu ao fazer o comando `php artisan db:seed` na segunda vez ele dá-me um erro de que o id de users já tem valor de 1 e não e possível inserir mais.

Eu sei que é possível verificar nos models do User se já existe um id igual ou não.

O que eu preciso é mesmo isso que nos models do User verifique se já existe 1 admin se existir ele não insere user mas insere o resto das migrations.

Deixo aqui as propriedades do model User

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode ainda verificar se o registro já existe através da própria API `DB` do Laravel.

```
if (DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->count() == 0) {

    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'id'=>'1',
        'name' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('admin'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ]);

}
```

Basicamente, o que o código faz é uma consulta direta à tabela `users`, sob a condição `id = 1` e conta os resultados. Se for zero, significa que o registro ainda não existe, então executa a instrução `insert`. Caso contrário, continue executando os `seeders`.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson Carlos Woss funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 3):

No seu caso você pode usar o método [`firstOrCreate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#other-creation-methods):

```
User::firstOrCreate([
    'id'=>'1',
    'name' => 'admin',
    'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
    'password' => bcrypt('admin'),
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
]);
```

Ele irá verificar no banco antes de inserir e persistir o User.